# Get button value in asp.net MVC by passing model class as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller as shown below. and my `Login` view i have following fields as shown below.

```
    // login model is my model class
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Login model)
    {
       return View();
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <p> 
    UserName: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
   </p>   
  <p>
    Password: @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
  </p>
  <p>
     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
  </p>  }
```

I want to check in controller whether user has clicked on `cancel` button or `login` button. how to  achieve this.

please advice thanks.

Comment: Give both buttons the same `name` attribute (same `name="action"`) and then modify the method to `public ActionResult Login(Login model, string action)` and `action` will contain the value of the clicked button. But the real question is why you think you would need to do that. If you click cancel, then you should not be going to that method in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the multiple ways to handle the more than one button in asp.net mvc. most commonly used is give the name and value to the input control and get the value on server side.
ie. cshtml page

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult actionname(string save,string cancel)
{
    string controlClicked = string.empty;
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
    {
        controlClicked  = "save";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cancel))
    {
       controlClicked  = "cancel";
    }
    return View();
}
```

---

Create button and provide action name in formaction attribute.

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" formaction="saveaction" formmethod="post" />
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" 
formaction="cancelaction" formmethod="post" />
```

The formaction attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. This attribute overrides the form's action attribute.
The formaction attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult saveaction()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult cancelaction()
{
     return View();
}
```